# How to rollout a Deployment in Openshift via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift

I switched from Deployment Configs to Deployments in Openshift 4.
In my Jenkins pipelines I had a step for rolling out the DeploymentConfig which looked like this:

```
openshift.withCluster() {
  openshift.withProject("project") {
    def rm = openshift.selector("dc", app).rollout()
    timeout(5) { 
      openshift.selector("dc", app).related('pods').untilEach(1) {
        return (it.object().status.phase == "Running")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the openshift-jenkins-plugin there doesn't seem to be an option to rollout a deployment. Deployment is also a native kubernetes object as far as I know opposed to the Openshift Object DeploymentConfig.

What would be an easy way to rollout a deployment in Openshift 4 in Jenkins?

Comment: is this rollout preceded by an image build?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kubectl with the Jenkin

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment/abc
```

you can use the [kubectl](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/)

```
node {
  stage('Apply Kubernetes files') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'user1', serverUrl: 'https://api.k8s.my-company.com']) {
      sh 'kubectl apply -f my-kubernetes-directory'
    }
  }
}
```

You can rollout the deployment as per need using the command line and if you can make or pass the variables also.

https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_rollout/

Answer (score 0):

Deployments do not natively have a rollout or redeploy option like DeploymentConfigs.

However, if you make a change in the Deployment yaml, a redeploy is done with the new configuration laid in. Using that idea, you can make a change in the Deployment's configuration that doesn't actually change your project and trigger that when you want a clean slate.

```
oc patch deployment/{Your Deployment name here} -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"last-restart\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

That command makes an annotation named "last-restart" and sets a value of the current timestamp that you run it. If you run it again, it replaces the timestamp with an updated value. Both of these actions are a change enough to trigger a redeployment, but not a functional change to your project.